# count rows respecting conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, distinct

does anyone knows how should i do to count the rows of a table where time and number are the same for different id.
For the case below, i want to have (0023: 2, 0024: 3).

example:

```
      id_, time, number

row1: id1, 12h30, 0023
row2: id2, 12h30, 0023
row3: id2, 12h30, 0023
row4: id3, 12h45, 0024
row5: id5, 12h45, 0024
row6: id6, 12h45, 0024
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you want `count(distinct ...)`?

```
select number, time, count(distinct id) cnt
from mytable
group by number, time
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), you can do:

```
with t as (
    select * from table_name group by id, time, number
)
select count(*) as cnt from t group by time, number;
```